# Specifying launching activity from preferences

Tags: android

What is the correct way to launch the preferred activity when the app starts?
For instance, I have 2 activities (1 being a help/login type activity, the other is the main activity), and I want to allow the user to define which activity is shown up on launch.
Do I need to use `SharedPreferences`?
What changes must be made in the manifest?
I've been unsuccessful finding a decent example online.

Answer (score 0):

Here a possible solution with SharedPreferences and with consideration of the App starts for the first time:

```
public class ThirdActivity extends Activity{
Intent myIntent;

SharedPreferences useFirstActivity;
SharedPreferences firstRun;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    useFirstActivity = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    firstRun = getSharedPreferences("com.mycompany.myAppName", MODE_PRIVATE);

if(useFirstActivity.getBoolean("useFirstActivity", true) || firstRun.getBoolean("firstrun", true)) {
         myIntent = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
         firstRun.edit().putBoolean("firstrun", false).commit();
}
else {
         myIntent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
}
startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

}

Furthermore, register ThirdActivity as the main activity in your manifest file:

```
     <activity
        android:name="ThirdActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Don't forget to register FirstActivity and Second Activity as well in your manifest!

```
<activity
        android:name="FirstActivity"
</activity>
<activity
        android:name="SecondActivity"
</activity>
```

Comment: I thought about this idea but that maybe there was a better way to do it or that the user might notice the third activity. This works, and if there isn't a better solution I will accept your answer. Thanks :)

Comment: Maybe you should have a Splash Activity and do that validation inside the Splash, so you won't launch the main.